# Prestashop 1.7 - On Update Executed Successfully but Returns Error on Front-End

Tags: mysql, database, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to execute an SQL query but was returned with an error below:

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1*

```
$option = Tools::getValue('option');

$sql = 'INSERT INTO `'._DB_PREFIX_.'slot` VALUES ('.(int)$params['cart']->id.', '.$option.') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_slot='.$option;
Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);
```

Upon checking in database, it was actually executed and ran successfully. But on the front-end, I was thrown the error above. I am using the hook below to execute my codes:

- hookActionCarrierProcess

I have tried $option = (int)pSQL(Tools::getValue('option')); but it returns 0 on save.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is $option value?

Comment: Value from a form I have created for a user to choose from a list of options. Thus, it will take the value and insert in database.

Answer (score 1):

If your value is integer: you have to use (int) before $option

If your value is string:

```
$option = Tools::getValue('option');

$sql = 'INSERT INTO `'._DB_PREFIX_.'slot` VALUES ('.(int)$params['cart']->id.', "'.pSQL($option).'") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_slot='.$option;
Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);
```

Comment: It is still returning the same error - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1. I tried removing "" and it returns another error, is my syntax wrong?

Comment: I also tried with $option = (int)pSQL(Tools::getValue('option')); but it returns 0 on save

Comment: If your option is integer, use this:    $option = (int)Tools::getValue('option'));

use pSQL just for string values.

Are you sure about value of option?

Comment: Yes, I have tried $option = (int)Tools::getValue('option')); but it still stores as 0 without any errors. If I am using $option = Tools::getValue('option')); .... it works but the error will show.

I will dig into this then...

Comment: Can you post final query that ran successfully on db?

Comment: The same I posted in this post. It ran successfully but returns an error. Database updated in proper.

Comment: Upon further checks, there is actually an error when I retrieve the value. I am checking on this but thank you for your suggestions.